# Why "required" class is added to only first div element, but not next two?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a new coder and this is my first attempt at coding.
I've 3 identical div elements (mandatorysex1, mandatorysex2, mandatorysex3), which differ only in their ID. I'd like them to show, depending on value of another input. Once showed, class of their inputs need to be changed to "required".
I could do (albeit, partially) both of above (thanks to lot of help from earlier questions on this forum).

However, only first div element is actually becoming required, but next two div elements are not. I tried various versions of codes, including putting each of them in different DOM etc., but it doesn't work. I also tried dynamically cloning them depending on another input value and then adding required class, but to same results.

Can anybody suggest what I could be doing wrong? All 3 div elements are identical, but....How can I resolve this?

Here is my HTML code.

```
//This is div with input value, which will display other div
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Total number of trials conducted by you *</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_of_sexs" id="number_of_sexs" required>
       </div>
      </div>
```

These are the div to be shown or hidden

```
//this is first div
    <div id="mandatorysex1" class="">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 1</h3>
      <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex1" class="">
//this is second div
    <div id="mandatorysex2" class="">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 2</h3>
        <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex2" class="">
//this is third div
    <div id="mandatorysex3" class="">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 3</h3>
        <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex3" class="">
```

jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
 //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of number_of_sex field changes
 $("#number_of_sexs").change(function() { toggleFields(); });

});
//this toggles the visibility of mandatory sex fields depending on the current selected value of the number_of_sex field
 function toggleFields()
  {

  if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 1)
    $("#mandatorysex1").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
  else
    $("#mandatorysex1").hide();

  if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 2)

    $("#mandatorysex2").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
  else        
    $("#mandatorysex2").hide();


  if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 3)
    $("#mandatorysex3").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
  else        
    $("#mandatorysex3").hide();

  }
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: ID must be UNIQUE. Change to class and `.classname` instead of `#id`. Also mandatory sex is no fun.

Comment: Same results- ID changed to 'more' UNIQUE ones; .classname used. no difference. About sex, yup agreed :) but can't help :-D

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion! I misunderstood it earlier and kept IDs of div elements unique. It didn't work then., But when I made IDs of input elements unique, it worked. See my solution below. Thanks again! You rock!

Comment: I'd like to add that "name" was more important than "id". I experimented by removing 'uniqueness' of names and it reverted back to earlier problem. Keeping "name" unique was very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to suggestion from [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan), I could resolve this. Basically, when the form was validating input fields, the first time it sees input fields with same IDs, it ends validation there. it seems to be not proceeding to next set of input elements with same ID.
So, first I changed the class of all input elements to required and then altered jquery to remove class. but, most importantly, I changed the "name" and "id" of all 'input' elements in last two 'div' elements and voila! it's resolved. Here is the revised script.

```
//this is first div
<div id="mandatorysex1" class="">
 <h3 id="sex_title">sex 1</h3>
  <div class="row">   
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title of sex</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex" required>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>animal population details</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details"  required></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">   
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label>Current status of sex</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status" required>
                <option>Ongoing</option>
                <option>Completed</option>
                <option>Stopped</option>
            </select>
        </div>
  </div>
</div><! id="mandatorysex1" class="">
//this is second div
<div id="mandatorysex2" class="">
 <h3 id="sex_title">sex 2</h3>
    <div class="row">   
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title of sex</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title2" id="title2" value="" placeholder="Title of sex" required>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>animal population details</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="population2" id="population2" value="" placeholder="animal population details"  required></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">   
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label>Current status of sex</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="cur_status2" id="cur_status2" required>
                <option>Ongoing</option>
                <option>Completed</option>
                <option>Stopped</option>
            </select>
        </div>
  </div>
</div><! id="mandatorysex2" class="">
//this is third div
<div id="mandatorysex3" class="">
 <h3 id="sex_title">sex 3</h3>
    <div class="row">   
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title of sex</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title3" id="title3" value="" placeholder="Title of sex" required>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>animal population details</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="population3" id="population3" value="" placeholder="animal population details"  required></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">   
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label>Current status of sex</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="cur_status3" id="cur_status3" required>
                <option>Ongoing</option>
                <option>Completed</option>
                <option>Stopped</option>
            </select>
        </div>
  </div>
</div><! id="mandatorysex3" class="">
```

here is the revised jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
//this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of number_of_sex field changes
$("#number_of_sexs").change(function() { toggleFields(); });

});
 //this toggles the visibility of mandatory sex fields depending on the current selected value of the number_of_sex field
 function toggleFields()
{

if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 1)
$("#mandatorysex1").show();

else
$("#mandatorysex1").hide();
.find(":input").removeClass("required");

if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 2)

$("#mandatorysex2").show();

else        
$("#mandatorysex2").hide();
.find(":input").removeClass("required");

if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 3)
$("#mandatorysex3").show();

else        
$("#mandatorysex3").hide();
.find(":input").removeClass("required");
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that "name" was more important than "id". I experimented remove 'uniqueness' of names and it reverted back to earlier problem. Keeping "name" unique was very important.

Answer (score 1):

May go without saying, but make sure you're including the jQuery library. Otherwise, add in `console.log(return value)` after each evaluation to assess how far the code gets before returning a result - where value would be the result you expect returned after a given call-back event should've been triggered, or simply a confirmation message that would only print to the console if the evaluation has reached a certain part of the code block (example given in code snippet below).

If I understand correctly, all field groups should appear with a class of "required" added to the `<input/>` tags if a value 3 or greater has been added - and this is what I see happening when I replicate and run your code. 
**See examples below:**
JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/guqegohuka/edit?html,js,console,output

As well as in the below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
 //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of number_of_sex field changes
 $("#number_of_sexs").change(function() { toggleFields(); });

});
//this toggles the visibility of mandatory sex fields depending on the current selected value of the number_of_sex field
 function toggleFields()
  {

  if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 1) {
    $("#mandatorysex1").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
    console.log('greater or equal to 1');

  } else {
    $("#mandatorysex1").hide();
    console.log('not greater or equal to 1');
}

  if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 2) {

    $("#mandatorysex2").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
    console.log('greater or equal to 2');
  } else {
    $("#mandatorysex2").hide();
    console.log('not greater or equal to 2');
}

  if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 3) {
    $("#mandatorysex3").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
    console.log('greater or equal to 3');
  } else {
    $("#mandatorysex3").hide();
    console.log('not greater or equal to 1');
}

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
//This is div with input value, which will display other div
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Total number of trials conducted by you *</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_of_sexs" id="number_of_sexs" required>
       </div>
      </div>
  
  //this is first div
    <div id="mandatorysex1" class="">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 1</h3>
      <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex1" class="">
//this is second div
    <div id="mandatorysex2" class="">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 2</h3>
        <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex2" class="">
//this is third div
    <div id="mandatorysex3" class="">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 3</h3>
        <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex3" class="">
</body>
</html>
```

You could also evaluate the expression using a switch case statement:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
 //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of number_of_sex field changes
 $("#number_of_sexs").change(function() { toggleFields(); });

});
//this toggles the visibility of mandatory sex fields depending on the current selected value of the number_of_sex field
 function toggleFields()
  {

var jQuery = $,
    val = jQuery("#number_of_sexs").val();
switch (val) {
  case '1':
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches 1
    jQuery("#mandatorysex1").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery("#mandatorysex1").find(":input").addClass("required");
    console.log('greater or equal to 1');
    break;
  case '2':
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches 2
    jQuery("#mandatorysex1, #mandatorysex2").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery("#mandatorysex1, #mandatorysex2").find(":input").addClass("required");
    console.log('greater or equal to 2');
    break;
  case '3':
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches 3
    jQuery("#mandatorysex1, #mandatorysex2, #mandatorysex3").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery("#mandatorysex1, #mandatorysex2, #mandatorysex3").find(":input").addClass("required");
    console.log('greater or equal to 3');
    break;
  default:
    //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
    console.log('Please enter a number less than 3');
}
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
//This is div with input value, which will display other div
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Total number of trials conducted by you *</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_of_sexs" id="number_of_sexs" required>
       </div>
      </div>
  
  //this is first div
    <div id="mandatorysex1" class="" style="display: none;">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 1</h3>
      <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex1" class="">
//this is second div
    <div id="mandatorysex2" class="" style="display: none;">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 2</h3>
        <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex2" class="">
//this is third div
    <div id="mandatorysex3" class="" style="display: none;">
     <h3 id="sex_title">sex 3</h3>
        <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title of sex</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Title of sex">
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>animal population details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="population" id="population" value="" placeholder="animal population details" ></textarea>
         </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Current status of sex</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cur_status" id="cur_status">
                    <option>Ongoing</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Stopped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><! id="mandatorysex3" class="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
    .find(":input").addClass("required")
```

with

```
    .find("#mandatorysex2 input").addClass("required");
```

also do the same for the 3 rd div also

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain more? May be, by showing the code. I'm a beginner. Thanks

Comment: `<! id="mandatorysex1" class="">` `<! id="mandatorysex2" class="">`  `<! id="mandatorysex3" class="">`  is used in your code at the end of each div.  please remove this tag.

Comment: Ok. Those were just markers. But, I removed and tried as well. Same results.

Comment: `if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 1)
    $("#mandatorysex1").show()
    .find(":input").addClass("required");
  else
    $("#mandatorysex1").hide();`   the problem may be due to comparison.. remove '>='  and only check '=='

Answer (score -1):

```
change your toggleFields function
function toggleFields()
  {
    if($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 3)
    {
     //your code
    }else if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 2)
    {
     //your code
    }else if ($("#number_of_sexs").val() >= 1)
    {
     //your code
    }    

  }
```